# Testing concrete methods in abstract classes using subclasses

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, testng, abstract-class

```
abstract class BaseClass{

      private final Dependency dep;

      BaseClass(final Dependency dep){
             this.dep = dep;
      }
      abstract void toBeImplementedBySubclasses();

      public int concreteMethod(){
              //Do some processing
              return any_integer;
      }
}
```

```
class DerivedOne{

      @Inject
      DerivedOne(final Dependency dep){
          super(dep);
      }       

      public void toBeImplementedBySubclasses(){
           //DO SOMETHING RELEVANT TO DERIVED ONE IMPLEMENTATION
      }
}
```

```
class DerivedTwo{

      @Inject
      DerivedOne(final Dependency dep){
          super(dep);
      }   

      public void toBeImplementedBySubclasses(){
           //DO SOMETHING RELEVANT TO DERIVED TWO IMPLEMENTATION
      }
}
```

I want to test concrete methods in abstract class.
Is it ok if I test the concrete methods in base class in the unit test for any of the two derived classes, or is there any other way?

So, if write test for DerivedOne class, it will include test for all methods AND the concrete method of the base class as well.
I know there is a thing "Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS", using which we can test abstract classes, but in my case my base class has some dependencies which I initalise/inject using super() insider constructor of my derived classes, so I cant be doing it using CALLS_REALS_METHODS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options which immediately come to mind here.

Firstly, you could write an abstract *test* class, which handles testing these methods, and then the test classes for your concrete implementations do the rest.  For example:

```
public abstract class YourAbstractClassTest {

    protected abstract YourAbstractClass getInstance();

    @Test
    public void testThing() {
        final YourAbstractClass instance = this.getInstance();
        instance.callMethod();

        Assertions.assertTrue(instance.someProperties());
    }
}
```

Alongside:

```
public class ConcreteSubclassTest extends YourAbstractClassTest {
    private final ConcreteSubclass instance = new ConcreteSubclass();

    @Override
    protected YourAbstractClass getInstance() {
        return this.instance;
    }

    @Test
    public void moreTesting() {
        this.instance.implementationSpecificMethod();
    }
}
```

---

You could also create a *dummy* subclass in a test class for it:

```
public class AbstractClassTest {
    private final AbstractClass instance = new AbstractClass() {
        @Override
        public void abstractMethod() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testThing() {
        this.instance.concreteMethod();
        // Just make sure this doesn't ever go near the
        // methods you dummied up above...
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't the second method you suggested trying to instantiate an abstract class, which is not possible.

Comment: I could instantiate a dummy instance of a subclass extending the abstract class, but again, why cant I then just test the concrete methods in the abstract class in the unit tests for any of the subclasses?

Comment: It's an anonymous subclass declared inline.  I.e.  I am making a concrete subclass of the abstract class and initialising that.  I'm just doing it without giving it a name.

Comment: And you can test the concrete methods in the tests for the subclasses.  And in fact, if you don't make the concrete methods _final_ (so that subclasses have the option of overriding them) you _should_ test them for all subclasses.  This is why I provided the first pattern first.

Comment: Yea realised the above doubt was silly.! Thanks a lot, you cleared a lot of things in short time.